# How to ensure garbage collection of unused accumulators?

Tags: garbage-collection, apache-spark, accumulator

I meet a problem that Accumulator on Spark can not be GC.

```
def newIteration (lastParams: Accumulable[Params, (Int, Int, Int)], lastChosens: RDD[Document], i: Int): Params = {
    if (i == maxIteration)
        return lastParams.value

    val size1: Int = 100
    val size2: Int = 1000

    // each iteration generates a new accumulator
    val params = sc.accumulable(Params(size1, size2))

    // there is map operation here
    // if i only use lastParams, the result in not updated
    // but params can solve this problem 
    val chosen = data.map {
        case(Document(docID, content)) => {
            lastParams += (docID, content, -1)
            val newContent = lastParams.localValue.update(docID, content)
            lastParams += (docID, newContent, 1)
            params += (docID, newContent, 1)
            Document(docID, newContent)
        }
    }.cache()
    chosen.count()
    lastChosens.unpersist()
    return newIteration(params, chosen, i + 1)
}
```

The problem is that the memory it allocates is always growing, until memory limits. It seems that `lastParms` is not GC. Class `RDD` and `Broadcast` have a method `unpersist()`, but I cannot find any method like this in documentation.

Why `Accumulable` cannot be GC automatically, or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UPDATE (April 22nd, 2016): [SPARK-3885 Provide mechanism to remove accumulators once they are no longer used](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3885) is now resolved.

There's ongoing work to add support for automatically garbage-collecting accumulators once they are no longer referenced.  See [SPARK-3885](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3885) for tracking progress on this feature.  [Spark PR #4021](https://github.com/apache/spark/pull/4021), currently under review, is a patch for this feature.  I expect this to be included in Spark 1.3.0.